# Prove that $2^x = 3 \cdot 9^m+5$ has no positive integer solutions for $m \geq 2$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that $2^x = 3 \cdot 9^m+5$ has no positive integer solutions for $m \geq 2$.

I noticed that $x \equiv 5 \bmod 6$ and thus $2^x \equiv 4 \bmod 7$, but that doesn't seem to help me since $3 \cdot 9^4 +5 \equiv 4 \bmod 7$. Pretty much any other mod I use doesn't seem to work so I think proof by contradiction or something may work better.

Comment: For $m \geq 2$, we have $3 \cdot 9^m+5 \equiv 5 \pmod {81}$, so $2^x \equiv 5 \pmod {81}$, meaning $x=23+54z$ for $z \in \Bbb{N}$. Don't know if this really helps, though...

Comment: Where did you find this question?

Comment: @alphacapture I sort of discovered it.

Comment: Mind if I ask how?

Comment: @alphacapture I was solving the question of finding positive integer solutions to $2^x = 3^y+5$. It is easily checked that $y$ must be odd. Thus, we may transform this equation into precisely the equation in my question, and since the only positive integer solutions to $2^x = 3^y+5$ are $(x,y) = (3,1),(5,3)$, this result must be true.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture; Given the context in which this problem appeared, I wouldn't be surprised if this turned out to be as difficult

Comment: @IanMiller Do you see my comment above?

Answer (score 4):

Any solutions must be fairly small - either $m \le 11$ or $x \le 20$.  I assume you have checked all those cases and found no solutions but the two you're already aware of; indeed, there aren't any.

Let's prove this - though with a warning: there's lots of computation and black magic ahead.

**EDIT: It turns out we can substantially reduce the amount of computation.  See edit at the bottom.**

---

Suppose $m \ge 12$, and work modulo $3^{12}$.  Since $2$ is a primitive root modulo $3^{12}$, we have a congruence restriction on $x$ modulo $\phi(3^{12}) = 2\cdot3^{11} = 354294.$  In particular, we must have $$x \equiv 199283\pmod{354294}.$$

Now suppose $x \ge 21$, and work modulo $2^{21}$.  $3$ is not quite a primitive root modulo $2^{21}$ - it generates an index-$2$ subgroup of $(\mathbb Z/2^{21}\mathbb Z)^{\times}$, but nonetheless we obtain the restriction $$m \equiv 15627\pmod{524288}.$$

Now let's look for small primes divisible by both 354294 and 524288.  It turns out that $$p = 1+11\cdot\mathrm{lcm}(354294,524288) = 1021636509697$$ is prime, and $11$ is the smallest number for which this is true.

---

Now consider the sets $$S_2 = \left\{2^{199283+354294\cdot k}\pmod{p}\right\}, \qquad S_3 = \left\{3^{15627+524288\cdot k}\pmod{p}\right\}.$$

It's clear from definitions that $$|S_2| = \mathrm{ord}_p\left(2^{354294}\right) = 720896, \qquad |S_3| = \mathrm{ord}_p\left(3^{524288}\right) = 649539.$$

So we expect approximately $$\frac{720896\cdot649539}{1021636509697} = 0.458\cdots$$ elements in $S_2 \cap (S_3 + 5)$.  If we have no such elements, then there can't be any solutions to $2^x = 3^m + 5$ with $m \ge 12$ and $x \ge 21$.

We get lucky, and there aren't any elements in the intersection!  ***TA-DA*** - there are no solutions other than the two you know!

---

In all seriousness, this shouldn't have worked.  $S_2$ is one-fourth the size we expect; $S_3$ is one-third the size.  And it was still about a fifty-fifty shot if there was anything in their intersection at all.  And $p$ was a factor of two smaller than expected.  We should have had to find much bigger congruences and use those.  But [black magic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95kCv10duFw) happened, and everything worked out.

One more remark: the reason we chose $p$ divisible by both 354294 and 524288 was that it forced the sizes of $S_2$ and $S_3$ to be fairly small relative to $p$.  But their product should have been roughly $11/2$ the size of $p$ in the worst possible case; as I've said, we got lucky.

---

**EDIT: Here's how to make the numbers involved much smaller.**

Work modulo $3^5$; then $x \equiv 23\pmod{162}$.  Work modulo $2^2$; $m$ must be odd.  Then work modulo $163$.  The only possible residue of $2^{23+162k}\pmod{163}$ is $139$, and $134$ is not a possible residue for $3\cdot9^m$ modulo $163$.  Hence we're done.

Comment: Do you think we could get the chance that the two sets will intersect to be as small as we like if we choose the powers large enough?

Comment: Your second solution (after the edit) is neat and elegant. Well done.

Comment: @IanMiller Given that there are 81 possible residues for $3\cdot 9^m\pmod{163}$, I'm not sure I agree with "elegant" - more like "lucky".  Thank you for the compliment, though.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose that $x$ is a solution, then:
$ 2^{x} = 3.9^{m} + 5 = 3.9^{m} + 3 + 2$, so:
$$2(2^{x-1} - 1) = 3( 9^{m} + 1) \Rightarrow (3.(9^{m} + 1)) | (2^{x-1} - 1)$$
For $m\geq 2$. But $2^{x-1} - 1$ is odd and $3.(9^{m} + 1)$ is pair.

Comment: "is pair" = "is even"?

Comment: Perhaps there is an obvious reason, but why can't the following happen? $$\begin{cases}9^m+1=\frac{2(2^{x-1}-1)}{3}\\ 3\mid 2^{x-1}-1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Now, you have your division statement backwards. $a \mid b \iff ya=b$, so you should have $(2^{x-1}-1) \mid (3 \cdot (9^m+1))$, except that's not a contradiction since an odd number can certainly divide an even one.

Comment: I've edited the answer, this solve your problems?

Comment: It is possible for an odd number to divide an even number, so I don't see a contradiction.

Comment: A pair number cannot divide an odd number.

Comment: @ReinaldoR. What do you mean by a "pair number"?

Comment: Sorry, pair numbers are even numbers.

Comment: @user19405892 This answer is still incorrect. They wrote the division statement backwards. $a \mid b \iff ya=b$, not the other way around.

Comment: @ReinaldoR. No, you did not solve the problems of your answer. Let's say I claim that $9^m+1$, being an *even* number is $9^m+1=2k$ and that it holds (as *it must*) $$\begin{cases}9^m+1=2k\\ 3k=2^{x-1}-1\end{cases}$$ where does

Comment: Ok, but $a = (9^{m} + 1)$ and $b = 2^{x} - 2$, but, $a$ cannot divide $2$, so, following the results.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with this proof. It is true that if $2(2^{x-1}-1) = 3(9^m+1)$, then $9^m+1$ must divide $2^{x-1}-1$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, all odd numbers are $3k$ ? I think isn't true...

Comment: @ReinaldoR. Not all odd number are in the form $2^{x-1}-1$ and not all odd numbers are in the form $\frac{9^m+1}{2}$.

Comment: @user19405892 I can see that if $2(2^{x-1}-1)=3(9^m+1)$ then $9^m+1$ must divide $2(2^{x-1}-1)$, but I do not see why it must divide $2^{x-1}-1$.

Comment: @alphacapture Because any number $\dfrac{x}{y}$, which is an integer must have $y|x$.

Comment: @user19405892 what are your $x$ and $y$ in this case?

Comment: @alphacapture $x$ and $y$ are integers.

Comment: @user19405892 I mean what are they in this particular case?

Comment: @user19405892 If a number $n$ is not prime it may not be true that $n\mid ab\implies n\mid a\vee n\mid b$. In fact, for $m=1$ and $x=5$ it's precisely what happens to $n=9^1+1$, $a=2$, $b=2^{5-1}-1$.

Comment: @abiessu There is a contradiction, though, as Reinaldo R. points out.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli The point is that the fraction is an integer.

Comment: @user19405892 Can you write out the exact fraction that you are referring to?

Comment: You can decompose $2.(2^{x-1} -1)$ in prime number, in $2^{x-1} -1$ decomposition has just odd number, then you can see the result, the answer hasn't nothing wrong.

Comment: @ReinaldoR. How does $2^{x-1}-1$ being odd imply that $9^m-1$ cannot divide $2(2^{x-1}-1)$?

Comment: $9^{m} + 1$ is even numer, and $m\geq 2$ implies $9^{m} + 1 > 2$, then cannot divide 2 and cannot divide any prime (odd number) of the decomposition of $2^{x-1} -1$.

Comment: @ReinaldoR. Note that when $m=1$, $9^m+1=10$ is still greater than 2.  How come your argument does not work in that case?

Comment: @alphacapture see my last comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39651/discussion-between-alphacapture-and-reinaldo-r).

Comment: Yes, this answer is incorrect. The expression $9^m+1$ is even so it will have a factor of $2$ canceled.