Solve $2^x=3^y+509$ over positive integers.
Solve $2^x=3^y+509$ over positive integers. My solution is as follows:
$$\begin{align*}2^x=3^y+509&\Longrightarrow 2^x-512=3^y+509-512\\&\Longrightarrow 2^x-2^9=3^y-3\\&\Longrightarrow 2^9(2^{x-9}-1)=3(3^{y-1}-1)\\&\Longrightarrow (x,~y)={(9,~1)}\end{align*}$$  but how can I see that this the only solution?
$(2^x-1)509=3(3^y-2^x)$ and $509$ and $3$ prime then for any $k\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, $2^x=3k+1$, $3^y-2^x=509k$ so  $3^y=512k+1$ but I can't show that there is no solution for this equation for $y>1.$
Another approach: For modulo 9 if we accept there is a solution to $y\ge2$ so
$2^x\equiv 5\mod 9$ hence $x=6k+5$ and x must be an odd number.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982329/im-having-trouble-understanding-hensels-lemma may help. Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3905310/find-all-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation-7x-3y4-in-positive-integers and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1781722/prove-that-2x-3-cdot-9m5-has-no-positive-integer-solutions-for-m-geq-2 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3493828/solve-diophantine-equation-2x-5y3-for-non-negative-integers-x-y

If there is another solution then $2^x-2^9=3^y-3$ whose only integer solution is when $LHS=RHS=0$

In general, if $a, b, c$ are nonzero integers with $a, b \ge 2$, then equation
$a^x - b^y = c$, has at most two solutions in positive integers $x$ and $y$. This is a result by M. A. Bennett (On some exponential equations of S.S. Pillai, Canad. J. Math. 53 (2001), 897-922). An online copy can be found here. Theorem 1.6 there also tell us there is no other solution for your case.

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  From where did you get this problem?

I don't know origin of problem; the teacher of my buddy asked the question to him.

@Anne Bauval:  I noticed that you changed the tag from [tag:number-theory] to [tag:elementary-number-theory], but according to the tag descriptions, only linear Diophantine equations are [tag:elementary-number-theory]

@J.W.Tanner Quote from the tag description: "For questions on introductory topics in number theory, such as divisibility, prime numbers, gcd and lcm, congruences, linear Diophantine equations, [...] and related topics." Thé tag "number theory" is for more advanced topics, to which this post does not belong.

For brevity, let   $X=x-9,$ and $Y=y-1.$
$2^9\mid3^Y-1\implies 128\mid Y\implies 193\mid 3^Y-1\implies193\mid2^X-1$
$\implies96\mid X\implies 6\mid X\implies9\mid2^X-1\implies 3\mid3^Y-1\implies Y=0.$
Addendum
In response to a comment by Will Jagy, here I explain how I came up with the above proof.  From $2^9(2^X-1)=3(3^Y-1)$, we have $3\mid2^X-1$, which implies $X$ is even (not so significant to my mind), and $2^9\mid3^Y-1$, which implies $\color{green}{2^7}\mid Y$ -- see here.  This means that any odd factor of $3^{\color{green}{128}}-1$ divides $2^X-1$.  My goal was then to find an odd factor of $3^{128}-1$ that divided $2^{\color{blue}{6n}}-1$, so I could then say that $9\mid3(3^Y-1$)
, leading to a contradiction unless $Y=0$.
According to Wolfram Alpha, $3^{128}-1=2^9×5×17×41×\color{red}{193}\;\times$
$21523361×926510094425921×1716841910146256242328924544641.$
If $5\mid2^X-1$, then $4\mid X\;.\;$  If $17\mid2^X-1,$ then $8\mid X\;.\;$  If $41\mid2^X-1$, then $20\mid X\;.\;$  Et cetera.
The only one that works is if $\color{red}{193}\mid2^X-1$, then $\color{blue}{96}\mid X$.  That's how I got $128$, $193$, and $96$.

good. I wrote little programs for this, how did you get the 128,  193, 96  figures?

@WillJagy:  I added explanation

You did not need the full prime factorization. Factor $3^{128}-1$ as $(3-1)(3+1)(3^2+1)(3^4+1)(3^8+1)(3^{16}+1)(3^{32}+1)(3^{64}+1)$, repeatedly using the difference of squares factorization, and seek a $6k+1$ prime divisor for any of these factors. The factor $3^8+1$ hits with a divisor of $193$.

Good point, @OscarLanzi

Suppose $y\ge 2$. Then the equation is doomed to fail $\bmod(9×13)$. Therefore no solution is possible except $(x,y)=(9,1)$.
With $y\ge2$, we have $2^x\equiv5\bmod9$ from which $x\equiv5\bmod6$. Then with this residue for $x$,
$2^x\in\{6,7\}\bmod13$
while
$3^y\in\{1,3,9\}, 509\equiv2\bmod13.$
None of the accessible residue combinations satisfies $2^x\equiv3^y+509\bmod13$.

+1; I think your argument is simpler than mine and more general — $509$ could be replaced by any $n\equiv41\bmod117=9\times13$

@J.W.Tanner The next such $n$ that gives a solution with $y=1$ is $\text{2,097,149}$, the general form is $8^{4k+3}-3$.
